# Does laravel 5.1 support user to user chat widget?

Tags: php, socket.io, laravel-5.1

Okay so I am building a website in laravel it consists of users which has one to many relationship with orders. What I want to know is if its possible to implement a messaging system with web socket for each particular order. So essentially user to user, with the exception of admin being able to chat via admin panel. Any advice on this matter will be great.

Comment: Use GooGle.. StacOverflow is for other type of questions!

Comment: I have been on Google but all I can find is chat room tutorials I am looking for account to account style of chat.